# Cannot return from outside a function or method?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, jsp

While developing a web application I want to perform certain validation check and only after sucesssful validation I need to post the form and redirect control to next page.

JavaScript code:

```
function fnCheckEmptyField()
{
    var strDomain = document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value;
    if (strDomain == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML = "Domain Name Field Can't be Left Blank";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Relevant HTML code:

```
<form action="Result.jsp" name="validityCheck" onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField()">
    <input type="text" id="txtIIDN"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnValidityCheck" value="Check Validity" />
</form>
```

The line `onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField()"` shows an error *Cannot return from outside a function or method* and after execution of the JavaScript function form is getting submitted regardless the text field is blank or not.

I have placed alerts inside `if` condition and it is sure that if field is empty function returns `false`.

I don't know what's wrong with my code and why this errors with *Cannot return from outside a function or method*.

What's the cause and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *the line `onsubmit="return fnCheckEmptyField()"` showing an error Cannot return from outside a function or method*

That's specific to Eclipse. Eclipse is wrong here, that line is perfectly fine. Just ignore  the Eclipse error. If you want, you can always disable its JS validation.

---

> *and after execution of the java script function form is getting submitted regardless the text field is blank or not.*

That's because your JavaScript function is wrong. You've 2 mistakes in your JS code.

1. The `getElementsByName()` call is incorrect.

   ```
   var strDomain = document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value;
   ```

   To retrieve an element by ID, you need `getElementById()`.

   ```
   var strDomain = document.getElementById("txtIIDN").value;
   ```
2. Empty values are not `null`, but just empty string.

   ```
   if (strDomain == null)
   ```

   You need to check its length instead.

   ```
   if (strDomain.length == 0)
   ```

   Or just make use of JS boolean magic.

   ```
   if (!strDomain)
   ```

By the way, the line `document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML = "";` is unnecessary in this code.

Comment: Good explanation. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353209 for related bug.

Answer (score 1):

remove the "return" from onsubmit attribut
your code should look like this

```
<form action="Result.jsp" name="validityCheck" onsubmit="fnCheckEmptyField()">

<input type="text" id="txtIIDN"/>
</form>
```

hope this solve your problem :-)

Comment: return is required since we expect the method defined in "onsubmit" is doing a validation and submit the form only if this method returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
var strDomain= document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value;
```

should be

```
var strDomain= document.getElementById("txtIIDN").value;
```

The text field has an id, not a name

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript expert but I think you should lose the return keyword in your `onsubmit` parameter in the HTML; like below:

```
onsubmit="fnCheckEmptyField()"
```

edit: sorry was posting concurrently with previous answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove Action from Form Tag.

```
function fnCheckEmptyField() 
{ 
   var strDomain= document.getElementsByName("txtIIDN").value; 
   if(strDomain == null) 
   {
      document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML=""; 
      document.getElementById("lblValidityStatus").innerHTML="Domain Name Field Can't be Left Blank";
   } 
   else 
   { 
      window.navigate("top.jsp");
   } 
}
```