# Error on OnClick function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Error on OnClick function. The error is "cannot return from out side a function or method".

HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height=atuo class="table_content">
        <tr class="tr_title" align="center">
            <td align="center" width="1%" class="table_content_td">
                <input name="chkall" type="checkbox" id="chkall" onClick="return cf_checkall('this.document.form1.chkdel',this.checked);" helpid="14">
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                RN
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Driver Name
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Phone Number
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Vehicle Number
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Fueled in Ltrs
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Fueling Time
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="12%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Region
            </td>
            <td nowrap width="15%" align="center" class="table_content_td">
                Assign To Department
            </td>
        </tr>
```

when i run this project then the following errors are displayed. please help me how to remove these error. I think its becoz of ClassPath or environment variables error. anyone guide me how to set the classpath or set environment variables for weblogic

```
The WebLogic Server did not start up properly.
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo; local class       incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7043855487133450673, local class serialVersionUID = 8644704819898565848
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:480)
at javax.management.MBeanInfo.readObject(MBeanInfo.java:669)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: **Java** is absolutely different from **Javascript**.o  Check this for how to use onClick: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onclick.  You only need the function name.

Comment: Might be a false-negative from the editor. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8930948.

Comment: you mean i dont need to put return in the Onclick

Comment: @JonathanLonowski then please tell me how this error remove if return statement is not causing problem ???

Answer (score 2):

Don't put return inside the onclick method, use this instead:

```
onClick="javascript:cf_checkall('this.document.form1.chkdel',this.checked);"
```

You neither need to return nothing in your function because input checkbox is not a submit button, then no event is fired, except onclick.

Do whatever you need to do in your function: fire events, etc.

Comment: i will try it now then tell you

Comment: bro i find there errors
    The WebLogic Server did not start up properly.
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7043855487133450673, local class serialVersionUID = 8644704819898565848
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:15

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you mean i don't remove return stament inside ?
then how this eror remove brother i am confusing :(

Comment: The webLogic server error is another question, update your question or make a new one

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, the `onclick` parameter will accept Javascript, though usually a function is used here.  It is up to the function to return, not here.  Therefore,

```
onClick="return cf_checkall('this.document.form1.chkdel',this.checked);"
```

should be

```
onClick="cf_checkall('this.document.form1.chkdel',this.checked);"
```

Also, make sure your function is properly defined and that *that* returns a value.

Comment: The extra `return` inside the attribute is one option for canceling an event -- stopping it from propagating/bubbling. Without it, a `return` inside `cf_checkall()` will have no affect on that.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you mean i not remove the return inside ?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski but bro in my all project where i use this function then the same error came every where

Comment: @MindBlowing The error you listed isn't a [`SyntaxError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError) and browsers shouldn't have an issue with using `return` in an `onclick` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/QGb7k/

Answer (score 2):

The error you listed doesn't appear to be a `SyntaxError`, but rather a [validation error that your editor is producing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930948). And, it appears to be wrong in claiming that it's an error.

The value of an [`onclick` attribute becomes a `function` body for the `onclick` property](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.html#Event_handlers), where using `return` is valid:

> Unlike the corresponding attributes, the values of these properties are functions (or any other object implementing the [`EventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) interface) rather than a string. In fact, assigning an event attribute in HTML creates a wrapper function around the specified code. For example, 
>   given the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div onclick="foo();">click me!</div>
> ```
>
> If `element` is a reference to this `div`, the value of `element.onclick` is effectively:
>
> ```
> function onclick(event) {
>    foo();
> }
> ```

I don't know how you can convince the editor that the "*error*" isn't real, other than to disable JavaScript validation entirely.

But, what you can do is apply the binding in a `<script>` with the [`onclick` property](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.onclick.html) rather than the attribute (i.e., "*unobtrusive*" JavaScript):

```
document.getElementById('chkall').onclick = function () {
    return cf_checkall('this.document.form1.chkdel', this.checked);
};
```

Note: This will need to be after the `<input>` in the markup or inside another event handler for `chkall` to be available:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('chkall') // etc...;
};
```